# How do I echo all users' display_name and their meta_value who have a certain meta_key?

Tags: mysql, meta-query, user-meta, meta-value, wp-user-query

I have a `meta_key` inside the table `usermeta` called 'sms_subscriber'. The `meta_value` for it is their phone number. I want to `echo` a list of all users who have that field; in other words, a list of each user's name, phone number, and the quantity.

The page output might look something like this:

**SMS Subscribers** (3) 
1 ben blue +15553335555
2 bob bananas +445557778888
3 jerry johnson +13334445555

I have tried many different queries and have successfully `echo` an array of users' `display_name`, and a list of `meta_value` with `meta_key` equal to `sms_subscriber`, but not in the same query. I've also got a query in Sequel Pro which outputs the `sum`.

Here are those:

Display the correct list of user's display names:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'sms_subscriber' ) );
$users = $user_query->get_results();
if (!empty($users)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($users as $user){
        echo ' <li>' . $user->display_name . $user->meta_value . '</li>';
    } 
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Display the correct list of phone numbers:

```
$phones = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'sms_subscriber'" );
$phones = array_keys(array_flip($phones));
// var_dump( $phones );
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    echo $phone . '<br>';
}
```

In Sequel Pro's query window, displays the `sum`:

```
select sum(um.meta_key = 'sms_subscriber'), 
from wp_usermeta um
join wp_users u on u.id = um.user_id
where um.meta_key = 'sms_subscriber'
```

Can you help me get these three queries working as one, so i can create the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to `echo` a list of all users who have that field; in other
> words, a list of each user's name, phone number, and the quantity.

Try this, which is based on your 1st snippet:

( and this is all you need; no need for the `$wpdb->get_col()` snippet )

```php
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'sms_subscriber' ) );
$users = $user_query->get_results();
if (!empty($users)) {
    echo '<h3>SMS Subscribers (' . $user_query->get_total() . ')</h3>';

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($users as $user){
        // this one uses the magic __get() method in WP_User, i.e. $user-><meta key>
//      echo ' <li>' . $user->display_name . " $user->sms_subscriber" . '</li>';

        $sms_subscriber = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'sms_subscriber', true );
        echo ' <li>' . $user->display_name . " $sms_subscriber" . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

#### Things to note:

- You can use [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) to retrieve the value of a *user* meta.

  Alternatively, `WP_User` has a magic [`__get()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php#L322) method which you can use to get a meta value without having to use the above function, but only to get a single meta value (regardless if that value is a string/text, number, array, etc.). So for example, you could use `$user->sms_subscriber` like you could see in the code I commented out above.
- To get the "quantity" or `sum` as you said it, which is the total number of users that matched your query arguments, you can use [`WP_User_Query::get_total()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/get_total/).

  If you just wanted to count the number of items in `$users` (i.e. the 1st page of the query's results — the results can be paginated using the `number` argument), then you'd use `count( $users )` in place of the `$user_query->get_total()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. - that did it perfectly! Also I really appreciate the detailed explanations - I will be using all of it, probably in this project. Thanks again @Sally.

Comment: PS: I revised my answer to correct a typo in the "magic `__get()` method" part. But actually, I added that part just so that you know; hence you should just manually call `get_user_meta()`, which is why I said, "alternatively". :)

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the detailed clarification!